# My autoencoder with all weights set to 0 works too well

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, autoencoder

I have an autoencoder model that I implemented using pytorch, and I noticed something strange. It was working too well without training. The model is as follows:

```
class ConvAutoencoder(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(ConvAutoencoder, self).__init__()

     # Encoder
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=128, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
    self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=1, stride=3)  # reduces height and width /2

    # Decoder
    self.t_conv1 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=64, kernel_size=(2,3), stride=(1,3))
    self.t_conv2 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=1, kernel_size=2, stride=(2, 2))

def forward(self, x):
    x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
    x = self.pool(x)
    x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
    x = self.pool(x)
    x = F.relu(self.t_conv1(x))
    x = self.t_conv2(x)
```

In my case my problem is anomaly detection, I have a dataset with the following form:

```
var1,var2,var3,var4,anomaly
-2.303138056500457,-6.356406683755182,4.718265100779811,-3.803123770009389,0
-0.6014388028983485,1.4546218686634245,3.803742475994967,5.437633496931176,1
```

The link to the dataset -> https://github.com/pablogarciastc/share_dataset/blob/main/anomalies.csv

If the autoencoder detects very high losses, the sample is considered an anomaly. The thing is that with the model with all neurons with weight 0, I understand that the loss should be quite random. However, it gives high losses right in the anomalous samples, which makes it get its anomaly detection task right, without having trained.

The code where the losses are calculated is as follows:

```
model = ConvAutoencoder.ConvAutoencoder().to()
model.apply(weights_init)
outputs = model(images)
loss = criterion(outputs, images)
losses.append(loss.item())
losses_index.append([data, loss])
```

I simplified the problem, and spared myself details such as the fact that being a convolutional model, the input samples are matrices, which are formed by taking a time window of the samples.

Thank you!

Comment: With zero weights, without training, it will gives just zeros all the time, for all inputs. Which mean huge loss every time.

Comment: @coder00 for example, if I test with 3 samples and one is anomalous and two are not, I am getting : loss:  tensor(0.8815)
loss:  tensor(0.9553)
loss:  tensor(1.1993) . The one with higher loss is the anomalous one, and this happens with all the anomalys.So, they are getting detected as anomalys, because I have a threshold that determines which ones are anomalous, and this threshold is calculated on the average loss.

Comment: Which loss are you using? This can be just because anomalous has bigger values(intensity). And what in the case of two anomalous? Anyway, my point is you can't initialize model with zeros, it should be random initialization(or pretrained weights). Second you have to train the model.

Comment: @coder00 sorry but I think this doesn't apply in this case.

Comment: Can you provide the link to your image dataset?

Comment: @adrianop01 is not an image dataset, but a tabular data dataset. The number of variables is the width and the number of samples is the number of rows, thus making matrices, which is what is introduced to the model.

Comment: 1. Include the tabular data dataset link in your question, without the numerical values it is very hard to guess the rationale. 2. What is the loss function for `criterion(outputs, images)`?

Comment: @adrianop01 thank you, is already updated with the link. The criterion function is :             criterion = nn.MSELoss()

Comment: 1. You would need to post the full code, like how you feed your data to your model for prediction, and what is `weights_init`? 2. The model architecture does not make sense. Why are you using 'Conv2d' if each sample is not a 2d image/tensor? Each sample (column) in your csv simply have 5000 features, **this is a 1d sample, not a 2d sample**. Did you reshape your data using `torch.reshape`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it worked too well is because of the way the anomalies were. The anomalies were well above average values. As the loss was calculated as the difference (MSELoss) between the model outputs and the images, for outliers, that were high values, far from zero, there was a bigger difference. This was because the model outputs, having all neurons at 0, were always 0. If instead of initialising the neurons to 0, I initialise them to a high value, the model will start to malfunction.